# Django TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str

Tags: django, typeerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2OSR.png)

class UserConfirmation(BaseModel):
TYPE_CHOICES = (
(VIA_PHONE, VIA_PHONE),
(VIA_EMAIL, VIA_EMAIL)
)
code = models.CharField(max_length=4)
verify_type = models.CharField(max_length=31, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', models.CASCADE, related_name='verify_codes', db_constraint=False)
expiration_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user.__str__())

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        if self.verify_type == VIA_EMAIL:
            self.expiration_tme = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=EMAIL_EXPIRE)
        else:
            self.expiration_tme = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=PHONE_EXPIRE)
    super(UserConfirmation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Include the full error text in the question, don't do a picture.